# How to fill in arbitrary missing dates in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My current dataframe:

```
   |   user  |       date        | count|
   | ------  | ------------------| -----|
   | user 1  | 2017-11-09        |   3  |
   | user 1  | 2017-11-12        |   4  |
   | user 1  | 2017-11-14        |   5  |
   | user 2  | 2017-11-11        |   2  |
   | user 2  | 2017-11-12        |   6  |
   | user 2  | 2017-11-14        |   7  |
```

What I would like it to be:

```
   |   user  |       date        | count|
   | ------  | ------------------| -----|
   | user 1  | 2017-11-09        |   3  |
   | user 1  | 2017-11-10        |   0  |
   | user 1  | 2017-11-11        |   0  |
   | user 1  | 2017-11-12        |   4  |
   | user 1  | 2017-11-13        |   0  | 
   | user 1  | 2017-11-14        |   5  |
   | user 2  | 2017-11-09        |   0  |
   | user 2  | 2017-11-10        |   0  |
   | user 2  | 2017-11-11        |   2  |
   | user 2  | 2017-11-12        |   6  |
   | user 2  | 2017-11-13        |   0  | 
   | user 2  | 2017-11-14        |   7  |
```

Any suggestions? I've tried doing the resample method, but I'm not sure that it works. Also, my dates are already converted to datetime objects.

EDIT: I'm thankful for the answers, but I've realized that my date column has multiple of the same dates, and indexing it is now an issue, because there are duplicate dates. Is there a way to approach the problem that doesn't require indexing (or gets around it?)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've edited the question though, and indexing is an issue with duplicate dates.

Comment: Please check edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, though I've edited the question as well after your answer; each different date is because of different users. I really appreciate the help by the way.

Comment: You are welcome! Nice day!

Comment: Some problem with my answer?

Comment: I edited the question after your new answer. I think it might not work, because I can't just aggregate the counts for each date, as there are different users.

Comment: Added to new solutions - first create for each group separately `date` ranges and second create `datetimes` by `min` and `max`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) working with `DatetimeIndex`, so first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
#if necessary convert to datetimes
#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.set_index('date').asfreq('d', fill_value=0)
print (df)
            count
date             
2017-11-09      3
2017-11-10      0
2017-11-11      0
2017-11-12      4
2017-11-13      0
2017-11-14      5
```

If there are duplicated `DatetimeIndex`, is necessary `resample` with some aggregate function like `sum`:

```
df = df.set_index('date').resample('d').sum()
```

EDIT if dont need all combinations of dates:

```
df = (df.set_index('date').groupby('user')['count']
        .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('d', fill_value=0))
        .reset_index())
print (df)
     user       date  count
0  user 1 2017-11-09      3
1  user 1 2017-11-10      0
2  user 1 2017-11-11      0
3  user 1 2017-11-12      4
4  user 1 2017-11-13      0
5  user 1 2017-11-14      5
6  user 2 2017-11-11      2
7  user 2 2017-11-12      6
8  user 2 2017-11-13      0
9  user 2 2017-11-14      7
```

EDIT1 For all combinations of dates:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['user'].unique(), pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max())],
                                 names=['user','date'])
df = df.set_index(['user', 'date']).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
      user       date  count
0   user 1 2017-11-09      3
1   user 1 2017-11-10      0
2   user 1 2017-11-11      0
3   user 1 2017-11-12      4
4   user 1 2017-11-13      0
5   user 1 2017-11-14      5
6   user 2 2017-11-09      0
7   user 2 2017-11-10      0
8   user 2 2017-11-11      2
9   user 2 2017-11-12      6
10  user 2 2017-11-13      0
11  user 2 2017-11-14      7
```

Comment: @BubbleBubbleBubbleGut - Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @hedebyhedge - Glad can help!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `date_range` and use `merge`

Example:

```
>>> pd.date_range(start=df.date.min(), end=df.date.max(), freq='1D')

DatetimeIndex(['2017-11-09', '2017-11-10', '2017-11-11', '2017-11-12',
               '2017-11-13', '2017-11-14'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Then

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame((pd.date_range(start=df.date.min(), end=df.date.max(), freq='1D')), columns=["date"])
pd.merge(df2,df, on="date", how="left").fillna(0)

date    count
0   2017-11-09  3.0
1   2017-11-10  0.0
2   2017-11-11  0.0
3   2017-11-12  4.0
4   2017-11-13  0.0
5   2017-11-14  5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

@jezrael's answer is really awesome! Just to add a bit if you want to use an arbitrary range of date:

```
more_dates = pd.date_range('20171101', '20171120')
df = df.reindex(more_dates, fill_value=0)

            count
2017-11-01    0.0
2017-11-02    0.0
2017-11-03    0.0
2017-11-04    0.0
2017-11-05    0.0
2017-11-06    0.0
2017-11-07    0.0
2017-11-08    0.0
2017-11-09    3.0
2017-11-10    0.0
2017-11-11    0.0
2017-11-12    4.0
2017-11-13    0.0
2017-11-14    5.0
2017-11-15    0.0
2017-11-16    0.0
2017-11-17    0.0
2017-11-18    0.0
2017-11-19    0.0
2017-11-20    0.0
```

Thanks @jezrael for the advice, edited.

Comment: Or better `df = df.reindex(more_dates, fill_value=0)`